# React.: Set Value of field array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, set, field

I have defined an array which looks like

```
 const [weekDays, setWeekDays] = useState({
        a: [
            { id: 1, weekDay: 'MONDAY', isChecked: false },
            { id: 2, weekDay: 'TUESDAY', isChecked: false },
            { id: 3, weekDay: 'WEDNESDAY', isChecked: false },
            { id: 4, weekDay: 'THURSDAY', isChecked: false },
            { id: 5, weekDay: 'FRIDAY', isChecked: false },
            { id: 6, weekDay: 'SATURDAY', isChecked: false },
            { id: 7,  weekDay: 'SUNDAY', isChecked: false },
        ]
    });
```

Another array which looks like

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([{"id":2,"messageId":1,"weekDay":"Tuesday"}])
```

Now I want to compare the array and set the isChecked value of the one array field true if the weekday exists in the other. So I want something like:

```
weekDays.a.map(weekDay => {
            array.map(row => {
                if (row.weekDay === weekDay.weekDay) {
                    setWeekDays([weekDay.isChecked = true])}
            })
        })
```

But I get the error Cannot read property map of undefined weekDays.a.map

How can the setter be done correctly?

Comment: Ps.: The String values in the weekDays array are also written the same way. so 'Tuesday' and not 'TUESDAY'. sorry. So this can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was you are comparing two different strings. I have used `toUpperCase()` method to convert all lowercase characters of the string "Tuesday" to uppercase so that the condition can be applied.

I have used index number to change the value of isChecked to true according to the applied condition.

```
weekDays.a.map((weekDay, indexWeek) => {
array.map((row) => {
  if (weekDay.weekDay == row.weekDay.toUpperCase()) {
    console.log(weekDay, indexWeek);
    weekDays.a[indexWeek].isChecked = true;
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have solved the problem. The strings are now the same and the loop looks like:  `weekDays.a.forEach(wd => {
            array.forEach(row => {
                if (row.weekDay === wd.weekDay) {
                    wd.isChecked = !wd.isChecked
                }
            })
        })` But I'm still interested in some things. So, in your solution, how do you set the indexWeek?  And is there a way to do this setter within the setWeekDay setter? Something like,  `setWeekDays(prevProps => (...prevProps, a.isChecked: true)) `?? I'm looking for best practice :)